# Git Inaccurately Detects Merge Conflicts

Tags: git, version-control, merge

I understand the importance of merge conflicts, however the way git has been detecting them has been pretty absurd.

I'm noticing that a small conflict on one or two line will often cause git to believe the entire file is different. I will frequently get a <<<<< HEAD and a >>>>>>> master that is essentially the entire file. Comparing them is a nightmare without using additional software like text-compare online. In fact, it detected a difference in .gitignore, and highlighted the entire file, but both <<<<< HEAD and >>>>> master were exactly identical. So a number of times now when I am fixing a merge conflict I have to go grab the developer and ask what lines were changed because according to git, EVERY line was changed.

I'm working out of Netbeans for the project and Notepad ++ for the .gitignore, but this is making managing the project very difficult.

Is there some setting or formatting I need to fix?

Comment: Is it possible that someone's editor is changing the formatting? For example, are the line endings being changed?

Comment: I have no reason to think it's doing that, since we're all using the same editor. Same version even. So unless git itself is going it . . .

Comment: Tell me about your line endings.

Comment: I have no knowledge about how line endings work beyond pressing "enter" when I want a new line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 git merge -Xignore-space-change
```

Should allow you to ignore all space related conflicts during the merge.

To be safe you should test it with the

```
--no-commit
```

flag so you can review the results before the actual commit.